# How do I find this multiple variable function limit, if it exists

Tags: calculus

$\frac {x(cos(y) - 1 )}{x^3+y^3}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

The cos really limits my options, since i can't use polar coordinates and if I try from different points it always equals 0. I was thinking about using L'Hospital Rule but I'm not sure it applies

Comment: You could always use squee's theorem you know $\cos (y) -1 \leq 0 \forall y$ use this idea to create an always larger or equal value using a basic function like I dunno y. then make an argument based on what x(y-1) does as x,y aproach 0, this will make your argument much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Just develop to the high enough power using a power series. You have

$$f(x,y)\approx \frac{x(1-y^2/2+y^4/24-1)}{x^3+y^3}=\frac{-\frac12 xy^2+O(xy^4)}{x^3+y^3}$$
where I also packed away the fifth order term into the remainder. If the limit exists, it should be independent on the angle of approach. Putting $x=r\cos\alpha$ and $y=r\sin\alpha$, you see
$$f(r,\phi)\to -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos \phi\sin^2\phi}{\cos^3\phi+\sin^3\phi}+O(r^2)$$
This thing very obviously has no 2D limit, because almost every angle has a different 1D limit on that section.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $y = mx$ and you'll find that the limit equals

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-m^2x^3/2}{x^3(m^3+1)} = \frac{-m^2}{2m^3+2}$$

Since the limit depends on $m$, you can conclude that it does not exists

(Note that if you found that the limit was not dependent on $m$, you could *not* have concluded that the limit exists. )

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how you got rid of the cos , and from where do I get $$ ( -m^2 * x^3 ) / 3 $$

Comment: hes using the power series expansion of cos.

Comment: @Speedy.RoGamer exactly as Faust7 says, I am using the fact that $\cos x - 1 \sim -x^2/2$. So there was a typo, it's a $2$ not a $3$

Answer (score 2):

If you pass to polar coordinates, you need to evaluate
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r\cos t (\cos(r\sin t)-1)}{r^3(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}.$$
Applyin l'Hospital's rule you get
\begin{align*}\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r\cos t (\cos(r\sin t)-1)}{r^3(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}&=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\cos t (\cos(r\sin t)-1)-r^2\cos t \sin(r\cos t)\cos t}{3r^2(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\cos t (\cos(r\sin t)-1)}{3r^2(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{-\cos t \sin(r\sin t)\sin t}{6r(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{-\cos t\sin t\cos(r\sin t)\cos t}{6(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}\\
&=-\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{-\cos^2t\sin t}{6(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)}
\end{align*}
which is not independent of the polar angle $t$. Therefore, the limit does not exist.